# The source list couldn't not be read

Tags: updates, appcenter

I'm new on linux and I don't know too much of linux. *noobie*

My source list crash when i was installing the repository of spotify. I dont know how to explain myself. I hope one of you can help me with this.

Thanks in advance.[image]

Comment: It looks like the word **sudo** is inside the spotify source list. Can you edit your question and include the output of the command `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list`?